# sharing files with script

Tags: file, google-drive-api, copy

I want to be able to write a script to share files within Google Drive folders using addfile.  However I'm running into issues getting to the correct folder for the from and to.  Example.  Share file1 in   drive/level1/master with drive/level1/foldera.  I have many files to share and copying/sharing them manually is time consuming.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with the script. Did you have a question?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Google drive apps.  Is there something else that could be used?